# Bootstrap SideBar Nav List into an Accordion (Error)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I have a sidebar navigation which just uses bootstraps nav list componenent. I want to add functionality that when it goes to tablet/phone that a button appears and I want to expand the list kinda of like the navbar componenet. When I went to implement this I get that if i hide my nav list and expand back to desktop mode my list is gone. I also want to add a button on certain list that creates an expendable tree.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span9">
            <h1>Header</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="leftcolumnheader">
                        <h5>Testing Home1
                            <button class="btn btn-navbar hidden-desktop" id="navlistbtn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse1">
                            <i class="icon-th-list"></i>
                            </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>

                    <div class="nav-collapse1 collapse in" id="sidebarnav">
                        <div class="well well-small ">
                            <ul class="nav nav-list ">
                                <li><a href="#">Object 1</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Object 2</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Object 3</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li> 
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--nav-collapse-->
                    </div> <!--well-->  
                </div>
                <div class="span6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code that implemented this, so we could see where things went wrong

Comment: http://codepen.io/nghi/pen/LoihJ

Comment: I meant editing the code inside the answer, but I did that for you now